# multiple mouseover-mouseout event when changing mouse pointer position on a div

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouseover, space

I have troubleshoot in my web project. I have a html code. It look like below:

```
<div id="my-div">
        <ul>
            <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
            <li>cccccccc</li>
            <li>dddddddd</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But when i change the position of my mouse position in my div, mouseover function works multiple time. I prepared an jsfiddle example to explain how my issue look like. The link is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/r7zhL0qa/2/

Please help me to overcome that issue. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: Please post all your code in your question (instead of only linking to jsfiddle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happening because you're using "mouseover" and "mouseout". These events fire not only for the element you attach them too, but also for its children. So you're seeing an event fire every time you move in and out of any of the LIs in your list.

The events you want to be using as "mouseenter" and "mouseleave", which will only fire for "my-div" and not for its children. Here's a modified version of your snippet using those events.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div'),
    counter = document.getElementById('counter');

myDiv.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    counter.innerHTML += 'in <br>';
});

myDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    counter.innerHTML += 'out <br>';
});
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
    <ul>
        <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
        <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
        <li>cccccccc</li>
        <li>dddddddd</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="counter" style="height: 500px"></div>
```

([jsfiddle of the exact same code](http://jsfiddle.net/r7zhL0qa/3/))